# Was compilation successful or not?

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode

How do I find out if compilation was successful or not?

I would like to have a variable `compilation-no-error` set to true after successful compilation.

I looked at variables and functions starting with `compilation-...`, but I could not find a simple solution.

Comment: What about variables `compilation-finish-function` and `compilation-finish-functions`?

Comment: I think, this [answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/336/101) could help.

Comment: @Nsukami_ Great, that answers my question!