# How do i close the *compilation* buffer without visitinig its window?

Tags: window, compilation, kill-buffer

I like to work with a vertically split frame with code in both windows. When i call `M-x compile` the `*compilation*` buffer shows in the other window (wich is fine as `M-g n` would show problematic code in the current window while i can still see the error in the other), but, after reviewing code, i would like to kill the `*compilation*` buffer and show the code that was in that window before, without visiting that window (`C-x o`) and killing it (`C-x k`).

Is there a way to do that?

I've come up with something, altough, it does not work; it throws:

```
wrong-type-argument windowp (#<window 10 on *Backtrace*>))`
window-buffer((#<window 10 on *Backtrace*>))
```

I believe that `window-buffer` does take a window as an argument and return its buffer, but I don't know any Lisp.

The code:

```
(defun kill-other-window-buffer ()
  "Kill the buffer of the other window if there is two windows"
  ;; I thought it will be better this way, to avoid killing an unexpected buffer
  ;; when several windows are in the frame
  (if (= (length (window-list)) 2)
    (kill-buffer
      (window-buffer (last (window-list)))
  )))
```

Comment: Doesn't pressing `C-x k` prompt you to chose the buffer you want to kill from the buffers list ? You can just chose the buffer you want to kill and press enter to kill buffer.

Comment: What @ChakravarthyRaghunandan said.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62/hide-compilation-window)?

Comment: How about?:  `(kill-buffer "*compilation*")`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Charkravarthy](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12247/chakravarthy-raghunandan) and [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew), using either vanilla Emacs, or together with `Helm`, `Ido` or `Ivy` one can kill / *close* the `*Compilation*` buffer using `C-x k` and selecting it when prompted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in the original function written by the author of the question.  The `car` function should wrap the `last` function because `last` returns a list.

```
 (if (= (length (window-list)) 2)
    (kill-buffer
      (window-buffer (car (last (window-list))))
  )))
```

However, after using this function, I found that (of course) it wouldn't work if there were 3+ windows open.

There's also `M-x winner-undo` which restores the previous window configuration.

I tested this with 2 windows open vertically, with FileA and FileB.  I compiled FileA and the compilation buffer appears with no errors, hiding FileB.  I ran M-x winner-undo and File B was again visible.

I also tested with a single window FileA.  I ran compile, and the compilation results appear in a new window below FileA.  `M-x winner-undo` restored FileA to be the only visible window.

There's many ways to do the same thing and it's a choice between whether you want to expressly kill the *Compilation* buffer or kill the most recent buffer shown in the most recent window.